# Pattern matching on rest of list

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to pattern match on a list of pairs, where I'm trying to return a list from the list of pair, however I'm having trouble figuring out where to make the recursive call. Without the recursive call I have this:

```
let countriesInChart (cht: chart) = 
  match cht with
  | [] -> []
  | (x,y)::tt -> [x;y]
;;
```

But naturally this only applies to the first pair in the list and simply returns `["countryA"; "countryB"]` without the rest of the list.

With the recursive call this simply only returns an empty list:

```
let rec countriesInChart (cht: chart) = 
  match cht with
  | [] -> []
  | (x,y)::tt -> [x;y]::countriesInChart tt 
;;
```

How would I make the recursive call such that all the pairs in the list would return as a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this:

```
[x;y] :: countriesInChart tt
```

This says to add a new list of two elements onto the front of a list of lists.

I don't think you want a list of lists, you just want a list. So you shouldn't be making a list of two elements.

If x and y are the same type (as I suspect they are), what you probably want is this:

```
x :: y :: countriesInChart tt
```

This says to add both `x` and `y` individually to the front of the recursively generated list.

You can also write this, which is completely equivalent:

```
[x; y] @ countriesInChart tt
```

However, this constructs a list of two elements only to throw it away. So it's a tiny bit of extra work for no benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Note that with the following:

> ```
> let rec countriesInChart (cht: chart) = 
>   match cht with
>   | [] -> []
>   | (x,y)::tt -> [x;y]::countriesInChart tt
> ```

You've basically just re-implemented `List.map`.

```
let rec countriesInChart lst =
  List.map (fun (x, y) -> [x; y]) lst
```

If a flat list is what you want, then as of OCaml 4.10 (release 2021) there is `List.concat_map`.

```
let rec countriesInChart lst =
  List.concat_map (fun (x, y) -> [x; y]) lst
```

A simple example:

```
utop # List.concat_map (fun (a, b) -> [a; b]) [(1,2); (3,4)];;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4]
```